# How to cast a DATE (OracleDB) to java.sql.Time with a native query?

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, nativequery

I have an Oracle database which holds a date and a time, which I receive via a nativeQuery. The returned objects are `java.sql.Date` objects which doesn't hold any time values.

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(SELECT_TIME_DATA);
Object[] dates = (Object[]) query.getSingleResult();
```

Oracle database saves dates and times in the datatype `DATE` so Java just returns it as `java.sql.Date`.

Is there any way to get time from the database?

Comment: how your entity look like?

Comment: or you can use TO_CHAR function of oracle to convert that  column value to varchar and then map it to string in java. Then parse that string to java's Calendar object.

Comment: There is not entity. I am not mapping it anywhere. The issue is, that this is a very bad designed database. The table itself doesn't even have any PK.

Comment: wait, why you are using `Object[]` ? you have many attributes to return, can you show us your query?

Comment: @YCF_L because it leads to an exception at runtime: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.sql.Date;